# Metrics for LVM2 logical volume

Tags: lvm

I'm trying to figure out how to get volume-level metrics for an LVM2 logical volume on Ubuntu Server 18.04. The [man page for `lvm`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lvm.8.html) indicates that `dmstats` is the preferred tool for this purpose.

> The following LVM1 commands are not implemented in LVM2: lvmchange,
>          lvmsadc, lvmsar, pvdata.  For performance metrics, use dmstats(8) or
>          to manipulate the kernel device-mapper driver used by LVM2 directly,
>          use dmsetup(8).

However, I can't figure out any permutations of `dmstats` commands to try to retrieve basic metrics about LVM performance. `dmstats` simply returns no output, no matter which parameters I use (aside from help).

I found a [document from Oracle Linux](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52668_01/F10134/html/ol7-bug-28642757.html) that says `dmstats` is broken, but I'm not sure if this applies to Ubuntu as well, or not.

**Question**: Can anyone tell me how to retrieve metrics / performance data for LVM2 objects?

Answer (score 1):

What version of LVM2 are you running? There was a regression in the dmsetup command (a change unrelated to stats) that causes dmstats to produce empty reports.

I fixed this last year:

```
commit 925aaf0b874fd92aec1b34f42d23987f65205ff9
Author: Bryn M. Reeves <bmr@redhat.com>
Date:   Thu Nov 1 16:49:05 2018 +0000

    dmsetup: fix stats report command output

    Since the stats handle is neither bound nor listed before the
    attempt to call dm_stats_get_nr_regions(), it will always return
    zero: this prevents reporting of any dmstats regions on any
    device.

    Remove the dm_stats_get_nr_regions() check and instead rely on
    the correct return status from dm_stats_populate() which only
    returns 0 in the case that there are regions to inspect (and
    which logs a specific error for all other cases).

    Reported-by: Bryan Gurney <bgurney@redhat.com>
```

This commit is on both the upstream master, and stable-2.02 branches (depending which version your distro is currently basing on).

I don't think a new release has been made from master yet, but this fix should be included in lvm2-2.02.183.